# save voice call for offline processing

Tags: android, sip, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I am building an android app which uses voice recognition of the two people talking over the phone. For my use case, I need to be able to save the audio call for both parties and analyze it later using Machine Learning algorithms.

Based on my research online, I see that Android, inherently does not support voice recording (due to legal complications). If, however, I do need to do that, i am planning on building my own 'Viber-like' app which the users would have to use for me to be able to save their voice.

I was looking into creating a SIP-based viber-like app for this use-case. Can someone suggest if I am in heading in the right direction? Or are their some already existing APIs that I could probably use?

Comment: _"I see that Android, inherently does not support voice recording (due to legal complications)"_. I used to work within this area, and I have never been presented with any legal (or other) argument for disabling voice call recording support. Indeed, almost all the phones I've worked on have had some level of support for voice call recording - and for the ones that didn't, it was due to technical reasons.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. In that case, what is the best approach to save voice calls? Do you think that idea of creating a sip based app in which all data goes through my servers seems reasonable?

Comment: If you plan to record calls on your server, or send recordings from the devices to your server, that's probably something that you have to make _very_ clear to the users in advance. I can't really judge whether or not it's a good idea, and I don't know much about SIP. As for recording regular voice calls; you just use the `VOICE_CALL` AudioSource for your AudioRecord/MediaRecorder.

Comment: Thanks, and does adding the VOICE_CALL audio source record the voice of both the parties?